# Michael Hartl guide chapter 5 LayoutLinks should have a Home page at '/' issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have been having this issue for a while now and I cannot seem to wrap my brain around as I have recreated everything from scratch numerous times

Anyways I am at the part of the book where we want the home page link to go from http://localhost:3000/pages/home (This worked perfectly by the way) to http://localhost:3000 
(basically meaning I want the home page to show up on the root page)

Currently the error i have is 
LayoutLinks should have a Home page at '/'
     Failure/Error: response.should have_selector('title', :content => "Home")
And underneath it is a bunch of text saying waht the page should look like.

Now I did 2 things, I first created the layout_links_spec.rb page, added the help page to the pages_controller.rb, and added the routes to config/routes.rb  below is the code for all 3

layout_links_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe "LayoutLinks" do
#  describe "GET /layout_links" do
#    it "works! (now write some real specs)" do
  # Run the generator again with the --webrat flag if you want to use webrat methods/matchers
#      get layout_links_index_path
#      response.status.should be(200)

it "should have a Home page at '/'" do
get '/'
response.should have_selector('title', :content => "Home")
     end

it "should have a Contact page at '/contact'" do
get '/about'
response.should have_selector('title', :content => "About")
end

it "should have a Help page '/help'" do
get '/help'
response.should have_selector('title', :content => "Help")
  end
end
```

Pages_controller.rb

```
def home
    @title = "Home"
  end

  def contact
        @title = "Contact"
  end

  def about
        @title = "About"
  end

  def help
        @title =  "Help"
  end 
end
```

config/routes.rb

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
match '/contact', :to => 'pages#contact'
match '/about',   :to => 'pages#about'
match '/help',    :to => 'pages#help'
root :to => 'pages#home'
end
```

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add "end" to the end of your routes.rb :)
There is a block, that opens with "do" and you didn't close it. Check the listing 5.20 carefully.

Comment: it was on there I just forgot to add it

Comment: what you mean check it manually? you mean if i do like a /home?

Comment: I mean do you see your home page if you go to localhost:3000/ with your browser?

Comment: nope all i see is the default homepage Welcome aboard
You’re riding Ruby on Rails!

Comment: :) delete index.html from public. By the way, remember this moment, you can stumble upon this problem later when you start implementing cache for your applications and it will be creating index.html in your public and you will be trying to realize what the hell is going on with your main page :)